# React - Did the use of ternary operator cause slow rendering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I just read the blog , can anyone look and told is it is the correct that the use of ternary operator cause slow rendering

**Avoid Frequent Mounting/Unmounting**

Many times we’re used to making components disappear using a ternary statement (or something similar):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DropdownItems from './DropdownItems';

class Dropdown extends Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false
  }
  render() {
    <a onClick={this.toggleDropdown}>
      Our Products
      {
        this.state.isOpen
          ? <DropdownItems>
          : null
      }
    </a>
  }
  toggleDropdown = () => {
    this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen})
  }
}
```

Since  is removed from the DOM it can cause a repaint/reflow by the browser. These can be expensive, especially if it causes other HTML elements to shift around.

In order to mitigate this, it’s advisable to avoid completely unmounting components. Instead, you can use certain strategies like setting the CSS opacity to zero, or setting CSS visibility to “none”. This will keep the component in the DOM, while making it effectively disappear without incurring any performance costs.

Is the above statement is correct and did you agree ?

Comment: Can you link the article?

Comment: @Y4glory https://alligator.io/react/keep-react-fast/

Comment: It doesn't tell you not to use ternary operators. It tell you to set a CSS property(like opacity or display none) rather than unmount the component. This is what causes a performance issue.

Comment: @Y4glory my question is also the same does it really cause the performace issue

Comment: Yes, it will, frequently mounting and unmounting components will cause the performance to be bad. But the use of ternary operator is not the thing that is causing the performance issue(that's the impression I get from the title of the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of what you're doing, it shouldn't cause any significant slow down.  However, if you wanted to not cause mounts/unmounts, you should consider adding a property to your DropDownItems component, something like `visible` which could then be used to apply styles to your child component:

```
<DropDownItems visible={this.state.isOpen} />
```

If you use the ClassNames library, it makes it pretty easy to dynamically manage your classes based on props passed into your component.  Then the class could manage the `display: block|none` CSS values, or as a really quick example with inline styles:

```
export const DropDownItems = ({visible}) => {
  const displayStyle = visible ? 'block' : 'hidden';

  return (
    <div style={{display: displayStyle}}>
      ... your items in here
    </div>
  )
};
```